# Elastic Search - Multiple phrase match in within a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search 8.2

I have a field named `product_name` (type - text, keyword) that contains names of products.

The product names have spaces. Ex: Orbital Keys, XPress Bottle Opener, InstaPress Coffee Maker,
Uno Comfort Wear etc.

I want only documents for Orbital Keys or InstaPress Coffee Maker.

I tried using, `terms` (using `must` because I have other conditions to add):

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                {
                    "terms":{
                        "product_name": ["Orbital Keys", "InstaPress Coffee Maker"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't return any results.

I tried `should` and `match_phrase` and it works:

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[
                {
                    "match_phrase":{
                        "product_name": "Orbital Keys"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase":{
                        "product_name": "InstaPress Coffee Maker"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is `should` the best way to find multiple phrases within a field or is there any other way to approach this problem?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made use of the [Term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html), in this case you have to use the keyword field in the query because the match is exact.

I imagine your mapping looks like this:

```
{
   "mappings": {
     "properties": {
       "product_name": {
         "type": "text",
         "fields": {
           "keyword": {
             "type": "keyword",
             "ignore_above": 256
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Your query with Terms should be this:

```
GET test/_search
{
     "query":{
         "bool":{
             "must":[
                 {
                     "terms":{
                         "product_name.keyword": ["Orbital Keys", "InstaPress Coffee Maker"]
                     }
                 }
             ]
         }
     }
}
```